# How to send Notification to multiple android devices in same request?

Tags: c#, android, push-notification

i am using the following code to send notification but it is for only one device but i want to send notification to multiple devices in same request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class AndroidPush : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string deviceId = "DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID";

    string message = "Lead Generated Please check Lead section";
    string tickerText = "Lead Generated Please check Lead section";
    string contentTitle = "Lead Generated Please check Lead section";
    string postData =
    "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceId + "\" ], " +
    "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
    "\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
    "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";
    string response = SendGCMNotification("my api key", postData, "application/json");
}

/// <summary>
/// Send a Google Cloud Message. Uses the GCM service and your provided api key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="apiKey"></param>
/// <param name="postData"></param>
/// <param name="postDataContentType"></param>
/// <returns>The response string from the google servers</returns>
private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    //
    // MESSAGE CONTENT
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    //
    // CREATE REQUEST
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.KeepAlive = false;
    Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
    Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    //
    // SEND MESSAGE
    try
    {
        WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
        HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
        if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
        {
            var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
        }
        else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
        }

        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        Reader.Close();

        return responseLine;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return "error";
}


public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
object sender,
X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
}
```

so i want to know how can i use this code so that it can send notification to multiple devices.

If anyone knows about this then please provide answer or suggestion for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or loop the desired devices or use PushSharp dll.

Comment: i got answer, i can do this without loop. just i need to create JSON array for registration_id and pass this to post data

Comment: Perfect then. That's the way PushSharp uses. Pass a List<string>

Comment: @AshwinUpadhyay can you please post working code